# How can I serialize a nested object with marshmallow?

Tags: python, flask, marshmallow, flask-marshmallow

I am new to using flask/marshmallow and I have an object that looks like this:

```
{'field_0': {'field_1': {'field_2': {'field_3': '...', 'value': 'this is the value I want'}}}}
```

Is it possible to define a schema for this using marshmallow without creating 4 nested classes?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

Here is the canonical way (dropping 2 levels to simplify the example)

```
class Inner(ma.Schema):
    field_3 = ma.fields.IntField()
    value = ma.fields.StringField()

class Outer(ma.Schema):
    field_1 = ma.fields.Nested(Inner)
```

You could use `from_dict`:

```
Outer = ma.Schema.from_dict("field_1": ma.fields.Nested(ma.Schema.from_dict("field_3": ma.fields.Int(), "value": ma.fields.String())
```

You could also invent complex way with metaprogramming (using `type` to build schema classes) but overall the simplest way is the first one above.